# Show that $f(e_G) = e_H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $(G, \ast)$ and $(H, \Box)$ are groups and that $f: (G, \ast) \to (H, \Box)$ is a homomorphism. Let $e_G$ and $e_H$ denote the identity elements of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

> Show that $f(e_G) = e_H$.

Let $g \in G$ and $h \in H$. Then $g \ast g' = e_G$ for some $g' \in G$ and $h \Box h' = e_H$ for some $h' \in H$. Since $f: (G, \ast) \to (H, \Box)$ is a homomorphism, we have $f(g \ast g') = f(e_G) = f(g) \Box f(g').$

If $f(g) = h$ and $f(g') = h'$ it seems to work, but we don't know if $f$ is subjective.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(e_G)=f(e_G*e_G)=f(e_G)\square f(e_G)$.

$f(e_G)\in H\Longrightarrow \exists\; h\in H\;\;e_H=h\square f(e_G)$.

So $e_H=h\square f(e_G)=h\square f(e_G)\square f(e_G)\Longrightarrow e_H=f(e_G)$

Comment: Why does $e_H = f^{-1}(e_G) \Box f(e_G)$?

Comment: It does not matter if it is $f^{-1}(e_G)$ (it is as a corolary of this). $f(e_G)\in H$ so there is $h\in H$ with $h f(e_G)=e_H$. Suppose $[f(e_G)]^{-1}=h$.

Comment: So for the last line,                                     $e_H = h \Box f(e_G) \Box f(e_G) =e_H \Box f(e_G)$ $=f(e_G)$?

Comment: @StVincent Sorry for the delay. Yes, that's it

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma.** If $x$ is an element of a group $(G,*)$ and $x*x=x$, then $x=e_G$.

*Proof.* Since $x=x*x$ and there exists $y\in G$ such that $x*y=e_G$, we have
$$
e_G=x*y=(x*x)*y=x*(x*y)=x*e_G=x\qquad\square
$$

Set now $x=f(e_G)$. Then
$$
x=f(e_G)=f(e_G*e_G)=f(e_G)\mathbin{\square}f(e_G)=x\mathbin{\square}x
$$
By the lemma, $x=e_H$.