# Alternate Proof to $f(e_G)=e_H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Is this proof correct?

Proof: Let for all $a$ and  $e_G \in G$ we know that if $f$ is a homomorphism from ${(G,*)}$ to $(H,o)$  then,

$f(a*e_G)=f(a)=f(a)$ o $f(e_G)$. Similairly $f(e_G*a)=f(a)=f(e_G)$ o $f(a)$. So we now know the following:

$f(e_G)$ o $f(a)=f(a)$ o $f(e_G)=f(a)$

At this point can one state that $f(e_G)=e_H$? Or will this proof be sufficient if $f$ is  a bijection?

Note that I have gone through all the proofs in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109810/show-that-fe-g-e-h) but no proof given is similar to the one I have written above.

Comment: Yes! I have corrected the error.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is fine, however it would be better to write $f(a) = f(a\ast e_G) = f(a)\circ f(e_G)$ instead of $f(a\ast e_G) = f(a) = f(a)\circ f(e_G)$ as this seems you are not using the axioms of a group directly. But, if $f(a) = f(a)\circ f(e_G)$, then multiply on the left by the inverse of $f(a)$ in $H$ to obtain 
$$e_H= f(a)^{-1}\circ f(a)= f(a)^{-1}\circ f(a)\circ f(e_G) = e_H \circ f(e_G) = f(e_G) $$

Comment: But I still feel that my idea might be invalid. How can one assure that

Comment: Where you state that: "At this point I can state that $f(e_G)=e_H$ is correct because multiplying by the inverse of $f(a)$ on the left of $f(a)=f(a)\circ f(e_G)$ or on the right of $f(a)=f(e_G)\circ f(a)$ yields the desired equality. This ensures that $f(e_G)=e_H$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to deduce from $f(e)f(a)=f(a)f(e)=f(a)$ **for all $a\in G$** that $f(e)$ is identity in $H$.

Alternate way I would say: under homomorphism, image of a subgroup is again a subgroup [can be proved by subgroup-test], then what is possibility of $f(\{e_G\})$?